# Carousel : Set first loop image as active item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using `carousel` in order to display some pictures from my `django` application. The carousel displays pictures from a list of pictures and I would like to set the first one as `active`.

This is my script :

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            {% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{ publication.id }}" class="active"></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="" alt="Cover page">
            </div>
            {% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
              <div class="item">
                {% thumbnail publication.cover "200x200" crop="center" as im %}
                  <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
                {% endthumbnail %}
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>{{ publication.title }} ({{ publication.pub_id }})</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I have this line :

```
<div class="item active">
    <img src="" alt="Cover page">
</div>
```

But I would like to set active the first element from there :

```
{% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
    <div class="item">
        {% thumbnail publication.cover "200x200" crop="center" as im %}
             <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}                   
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How I could make that ?

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

I tried something like this in my code but it doesn't work :

```
{% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
    <div class="item {% if loop.index == 1 %} active {% endif %}">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a "active" class to a carousel first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960163/how-to-add-a-active-class-to-a-carousel-first-element)

Comment: @LaljiTadhani It's php code, I never used PHP code .. Furthermore, my script in only with bootstrap to this part. I agree it could be a duplicate, but your answer doesn't help me to find the solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something with Javascript. I removed `active` class in my code and I wrote :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').find('.item').first().addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

It seems to work fine ;)

Comment: Can you please update vanillajs equivalent to this.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who is searching for Plain Javascript answer for this.

```
<script>
 document.querySelector(".carousel-inner").firstChild.classList.add("active");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the ff:

```
{% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
   <div class="item {% if loop.first %} active {% endif %}">

   /* more codes */
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for publication in publication_list_carousel %}
   <div class="item {% if loop.index0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}">
   
   /* more codes */
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "{% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}" worked for me.